# Get elevation of a lat/lon point on map

Tags: wpf, runtime, arcgis

I have an application on ARCGIS RUNTIME WPF.
I work with a map  TPK file built in ARCMAP
I have also DT2 files for terrain elevation
How I can use TPK and DT2 files to get elevation in a point on the map?
Thanks

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: I didn't understand 1 abbreviation you wrote. Please be more specific and provide what you have tried.

Comment: DT2 is the suffix of a Digital Terrain Elevation Data [DTED] file level 2. TPK is the suffix of a Tile Package built with ARC MAP and used by my Runtime Wpf application as a MAP